# MATLAB - readtable() only reads .csv column if I expand it in Excel first

Tags: excel, matlab, csv

I am encountering some very strange behavior with my MATLAB program. I have three separate folders where I am writing .csv files of data with the first column being date and time in "MM/DD/YYY HH:mm:SS" format, and the other column(s) being sensor output. I have a program which compiles a list of the files in each of the three destination folders and reads through them one at a time, adding these data to arrays and then plotting them.

```
for k = 1:length(fileList_O2)
    baseFileName = fileList_O2(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(fileList_O2(k).folder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    data = readtable(fullFileName);
    timecol = data(:,1);
    EZOO2col = data(:, 2);
    
    timecol_array_O2 = table2array(timecol);
    EZOO2col_array = table2array(EZOO2col);
    EZOO2col_double = str2double(EZOO2col_array);
    
    if k == 1
        timecol_tot_O2  = timecol_array_O2;
        EZOO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOO2col_tot, EZOO2col_double);
    else
        timecol_tot_O2  = cat(1, timecol_tot_O2, timecol_array_O2);
        EZOO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOO2col_tot, EZOO2col_double);
    end
end

for k = 1:length(fileList_CO2)
    baseFileName = fileList_CO2(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(fileList_CO2(k).folder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    data = readtable(fullFileName);
    timecol_CO2 = data(:,1);
    EZOCO2col = data(:,2);
    
    timecol_array_CO2 = table2array(timecol_CO2);
    EZOCO2col_array = table2array(EZOCO2col);
    EZOCO2col_double = str2double(EZOCO2col_array);
    
    if k == 1
        timecol_tot_CO2  = timecol_array_CO2;
        EZOCO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOCO2col_tot, EZOCO2col_double);
    else
        timecol_tot_CO2  = cat(1, timecol_tot_CO2, timecol_array_CO2);
        EZOCO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOCO2col_tot, EZOCO2col_double);
    end
end

for k = 1:length(fileList_RB)
    baseFileName = fileList_RB(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(fileList_RB(k).folder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    data = readtable(fullFileName);
    timecol_RB = data(:,1);
    SGP30CO2col = data(:, 2);
    SGP30TVOCcol = data(:, 3);
    BME280Humcol = data(:, 4);
    BME280Presscol = data(:, 5);
    BME280Tempcol = data(:, 6);
    
    timecol_array_RB = table2array(timecol_RB);
    datetime(timecol_array_RB); %, 'InputFormat', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'Format', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    SGP30CO2col_array = table2array(SGP30CO2col);
    SGP30TVOCcol_array = table2array(SGP30TVOCcol);
    BME280Humcol_array = table2array(BME280Humcol);
    BME280Presscol_array = table2array(BME280Presscol);
    BME280Tempcol_array = table2array(BME280Tempcol);
    
    if k == 1;
        timecol_tot_RB  = timecol_array_RB;
        SGP30CO2col_tot = cat(1, SGP30CO2col_tot, SGP30CO2col_array);
        SGP30TVOCcol_tot = cat(1, SGP30TVOCcol_tot, SGP30TVOCcol_array);
        BME280Humcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Humcol_tot, BME280Humcol_array);
        BME280Presscol_tot = cat(1, BME280Presscol_tot, BME280Presscol_array);
        BME280Tempcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Tempcol_tot, BME280Tempcol_array);
    else
        timecol_tot_RB  = cat(1, timecol_tot_RB, timecol_array_RB);
        SGP30CO2col_tot = cat(1, SGP30CO2col_tot, SGP30CO2col_array);
        SGP30TVOCcol_tot = cat(1, SGP30TVOCcol_tot, SGP30TVOCcol_array);
        BME280Humcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Humcol_tot, BME280Humcol_array);
        BME280Presscol_tot = cat(1, BME280Presscol_tot, BME280Presscol_array);
        BME280Tempcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Tempcol_tot, BME280Tempcol_array);
    end
end
```

Normally, when I open the .csv files in Excel, the date/time column looks like `######` because it does not have enough space to display the data in the standard width of an Excel column. I expanded the date/time column in the first two files of a folder, and now the program no longer recognizes the date/time column of the rest of the files as having valid format. It runs into an error on the third file - the first one in the list that has *not* been opened in Excel and has *not* had the column expanded in Excel to fit the length of the data. Here is the error message:

```
Now reading C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test Data\Bucket 1 (Control)\Test 1\O2\O2_Bucket_1_09-16-2022_16;28;31.csv
Now reading C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test Data\Bucket 1 (Control)\Test 1\O2\O2_Bucket_1_09-16-2022_17;28;32.csv
Now reading C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test Data\Bucket 1 (Control)\Test 1\O2\O2_Bucket_1_09-16-2022_18;28;32.csv
Error using datetime/cat (line 1378)
Unable to convert text array to a datetime array because the format was not recognized.

Error in Plot_attempt_9_23_22 (line 69)
        timecol_tot_O2  = cat(1, timecol_tot_O2, timecol_array_O2);
```

Before I expanded the date/time column in *any* of the files, the date/time was imported by the program in (example) `09-16-2022 16` form, rather than, say, `09-16-2022 16:45:31`.

What the heck is happening here?

Comment: Microsoft Excel has many formatting options that change what is displayed in a sheet vs the contents of the file. Open your .csv files in a text editor (for example, the Matlab Editor) and see what the contents of the file actually are.

Comment: @mhopeng I have already done so, and the contents show 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:SS' in Notepad, Notepad++, and in Excel when I select the cells.

Comment: Well if that does not answer your question, I suggest you re-state the problem with a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a sample data file.